# Place decimal before last two digits for an integer

Tags: python

I have a interger value like:

```
99990
```

I want this value to be converted into like:

```
999.90
```

Regardless of the length of the number, I need to display the number with 2 decimal places at the end, and I'd like to do it in an efficient way. The purpose is to display money amount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work quickly and easily.

```
print "%.2f" % (99990 / 100.0)
```

Answer (score 4):

With an integer value, you can use `divmod` to produce separate dollar and cent components.

```
dollars, cents = divmod(value, 100)
print("{0}.{1}".format(dollars, cents))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format) here:

```
>>> n = 99990
>>> format(n / 100, '.02f')
'999.90'
>>>
```

The result needs to be a string because Python automatically removes the trailing `0` with numbers:

```
>>> n = 99990
>>> n / 100
999.9
>>>
```

---

For those who are still using Python 2.x, you will need to divide the number by a float:

```
>>> n = 99990
>>> format(n / 100.0, '.02f')
'999.90'
>>>
```

Comment: You need to divide by `100.0` or `100.` instead of just `100`, otherwise the result is an integer.

Comment: @TheSoundDefense - Not in Python 3.x.  The OP never gave a specific version, so I used the newest.

Answer (score 0):

Dividing with a float 100. value should covert it into a float. After that, it's only a matter of formatting to display it the way you like.

```
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> number = 99990
>>> print("{0:.2f}".format(number / 100.))
999.90
```

Answer (score -1):

```
word = 99990
wordString = str(word)[0:-2] + "." + str(word)[-2:]
print(wordString)
```

Here's a little code snippet that will word, it converts the number to the string

Answer (score -1):

yet another way,

```
str(99990 * 0.01) + '0'
```